# How to Split screen height in half in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I want to split my screen in half horizontally in Jetpack Compose like this:
[image]

```
    @Composable
fun Splash(alpha: Float) {
    val configuration = LocalConfiguration.current
    val screenHeight = configuration.screenHeightDp.dp
    val screenWidth = configuration.screenWidthDp.dp
    val composition by rememberLottieComposition(LottieCompositionSpec.RawRes(R.raw.cat2))
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(Blue)
            .height(screenHeight /  2)
            .padding(8.dp),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.TopCenter
    ) {
        Column() {
            Text(text = "Example", fontSize = 44.sp)
        }
    }
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(Red)
            .height(screenHeight /  2)
            .padding(8.dp),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.BottomCenter
    ){
        Column {
           
            Text(text = "Example", textAlign = TextAlign.End, color = Grey, fontSize = 12.sp)
        }
    }
}
```

I can get screen height with LocalConfiguration.current in dp and I set my top box and bottom box alignments as Alignment.TopCenter and Alignment.BottomCenter respectively but it didn't work. Second box(Red one) stays on top of the blue one.

Answer (score 16):

The simplest way to set a height equal to the half-screen height is with a fractional in the modifier.

```
Column(
    modifier = Modifier
        .padding(10.dp)
        .fillMaxHeight(0.5f)
        ){ //Content}
```

Comment: This expands to half of the remaining space, but not half of the screen.

Answer (score 11):

You can wrap your `Box`es with a Column and set Modifier.weight(1f) for each box to set both of them at same height with

```
@Composable
fun Splash() {

    Column(modifier =Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .background(Blue)
                .weight(1f)
                .padding(8.dp),
            contentAlignment = Alignment.TopCenter
        ) {
            Column() {
                Text(text = "Example", fontSize = 44.sp)
            }
        }
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .background(Red)
                .weight(1f)
                .padding(8.dp),
            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
        ){
            Column {

                Text(text = "Example", textAlign = TextAlign.End, color = DarkGray, fontSize = 12.sp)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

or wrap with a `BoxWithConstraints` which returns `Contraints`, `maxWidth`, `maxHeight` and use `Modifier.align` to one Box to top and other one to Bottom. `BoxWithConstraints` is useful for getting measurement parameters and set them as children Modifiers.

```
@Composable
fun Splash2() {
    BoxWithConstraints(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .background(Blue)
                .height(maxHeight/2)
                .align(Alignment.TopStart)
                .padding(8.dp),
            contentAlignment = Alignment.TopCenter
        ) {
            Column() {
                Text(text = "Example", fontSize = 44.sp)
            }
        }
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .background(Red)
                .align(Alignment.BottomStart)
                .height(maxHeight/2)
                .padding(8.dp),
            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
        ){
            Column {

                Text(text = "Example", textAlign = TextAlign.End, color = DarkGray, fontSize = 12.sp)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I think i found a solution; no need for 2 Boxes, top Column will be the parent of bottom Column, and it will have max height, child column will have screenHeight/2 height

Comment: Added Boxes because your question included them. Simplest way to divide screen height between Composables is to use `Modifier.weight(1f)` for children Composables of a `Column`. Second alternative, BoxWithConstrains` returns dimensions and `Constraints` which can help you to divide its space between its children if more specific partition is required.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to implement your image is this way:

```
            Column(
                Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .padding(8.dp)
            ) {
                Row(
                    Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .weight(1f)
                        .background(Blue),
                    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
                    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
                ) {
                    Text(text = "Example", fontSize = 44.sp)
                }
                Row(
                    Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .weight(1f)
                        .background(Red),
                    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
                    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
                ) {
                    Text(text = "Example", fontSize = 44.sp)
                }
            }
```